# Updating SurfaceView with multiple dirty rectangles

Tags: android, surfaceview

In the project I am working on I decided to use SurfaceView instead of a custom double buffered medium. It provides everything I need and it's already double buffered.
 The problem is that it wont let me specify multiple dirty rectangles to redraw.
 SurfaceView.lockCanvas(Rect) only allows single rectangle and without parameter it's pretty expensive to redraw whole thing. Another solution to call lockCanvas(Rect) for each Rect causes eye-bleeding blinking in the screen, obviously.
 Do you have any solution giving the opportunity staying inside Android API field, if not do you have any external alternatives I can use?

Comment: are your dirty rectangles close together?

Comment: Oh, I commented on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the dirty areas before you need to call lockCanvas (sounds like you might), you could calculate a "super rectangle" that locks an area that contains all of your rectangle. For example if your rectangles are (using l,r,t,b coordinates)  [0,10,0,20] and [15,30,10,35], your super rectangle would be [0,30,0,35].

Comment: sorry, i thought of this, but rectangles are positioned arbitrarily. And they are most likely to be far from each other, which is slightly better than redrawing whole, but still inefficient.